# Submit button for jquery autocomplete ajax action Rails Edit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an edit form and on it I want to allow users to add tags using an AJAX call. I have the autocomplete working for when an item in the autocomplete matches what the person wants. When the autocomplete dropdown suggestion is highlighted and they hit TAB it will perform the AJAX action because I have set `autofocus:true`. And if they click on an item in the autocomplete list it will also submit like it should. But I want to be able to also create new tags that aren't in the dropdown list. If the user types in a word that doesn't already exist as a tag there is no way to get it to submit. I added an `Add Tag` button next to the text field but not sure how to get it to call the AJAX action.

HTML:

```
<div class="field h4">
        Add Tags:<%= text_field_tag 'add_tag' %>
        <button id="tag-submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-brand">Add Tag</button>
      </div>
```

the script:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var availableTags = <%= raw( Tag.all.pluck(:name) ) %>;

    $("#add_tag")
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .on("keydown", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            autoFocus: true,
            source: availableTags,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/add_tag",
                    data: {
                        ppe: {
                            id: <%= @ppe.id %>,
                            new_tag: ui.item.value
                        }
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        return false;
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

As you can see at the top of the script if the menu is active because there is an autocomplete suggestion the TAB key will work. But how do I tell it to call the `select:` event in the `.autocomplete` on the ENTER key or on clicking the Add Tag button? I've tried things like:

```
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).autocomplete("instance").select();
            return false;
 }
```

But I'm just guessing as my grasp of JS is very poor and I always end up banging my head against a wall on things like this that seem simple. I understand I could probably just build a whole other AJAX submit in the ENTER keypress function but why repeat all of that code. Also the button seems like it should be easy but I can't quite figure it out. To be clear I don't want to submit the overall page form until THAT submit button is clicked.